# Call DispatchGroup() in the right place

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase-realtime-database, dispatch, dispatch-async

I would like to use `DisaptchGroup` to call `func` after iterate through and append elements into array.

here is firebase node looks like

```
 {
       "tags": {
           "NewYork": {
                 uid1: 1
                 uid2: 1
           }, 
          "baseball": {
                 uid1: 1
           }
        }
    }
```

So, basically what I'm doing is after user selected tags, fetch uids under the tags and pass those uids to the array.

```
func filterTempo(filterTag: FilteredTags) {

        let group = DispatchGroup()
        let tag = filterTag.selectedTag.components(separatedBy: "/") //it reutrns "NewYork" and "baseball"

            tag.forEach { (key) in
                self.ref.child("tags").child(key).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] else { return }
                    for (key,_) in dictionary {
                        self.arrays.append(key)
                    }
           // want call func after iteration has finished.
                }, withCancel: nil)
            }
    }//func
```

After first iteration, array will be like this `[uid1, uid2]`. Then after second iteration, array will look like this `[uid1, uid2, uid1]`. I would like to call function( `func fetchTeams(array: [String])` ) after iteration has completed not mid-way. To achieve that I tried to use `DispatchGroup` but I tried `print(array)` in the `func fetchTeams` and it returns like so.

```
[uid1, uid2]
[uid1, uid2, uid1]
```

Where should I call `DispatchGroup.enter()` and `DispatchGroup.leave()` to fix this?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `group.enter()` everytime just *before* you call `observe`. Inside each `observe` closure, after the work has been done, you call `group.leave()`.
Once the number of `enter` and `leave` calls cancel out (e.g. all entered blocks have been left), the `queue.notifiy` closure will be called, where you then call `fetchTerms` or something else:

```
func filterTempo(filterTag: FilteredTags) {

    let group = DispatchGroup()
    let tag = filterTag.selectedTag.components(separatedBy: "/") //it reutrns "NewYork" and "baseball"

        tag.forEach { (key) in
            group.enter()
            self.ref.child("tags").child(key).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:Any] else { return }
                for (key,_) in dictionary {
                    self.arrays.append(key)
                }
                group.finished()
            }, withCancel: {
                // Maybe do some error handling here.
                group.finished()
            })
        }
        group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main)  {
            // called after all blocks have been finished.
            self.fetchTeams(self.arrays)
        }
}//func
```